# get a value deeply in a multi-dimension array by a sequence of keys

Tags: php, arrays

If an array `$array`

and keys sequence `$keys = array('key1','key2','key3')`

how to get `$array[$keys[1]][$keys[2]][$keys[3]]` given the number of keys is unsure, there could be 4 keys, or 1 key, etc.?

My code currently is:

```
switch(count($keys)) {
    case 1:
        if(array_isset($array[$keys[0]]), $array)
            $value = $array[$keys[0]];
        break;
    case 2:
        if(array_isset($array[$keys[0]][$keys[1]]), $array[$keys[0]])
            $value = $array[$keys[0]][$keys[1]];
        break;
    case 3:
        if(array_isset($array[$keys[0]][$keys[1]][$keys[2]]), $array[$keys[0]][$keys[1]])
            $value = $array[$keys[0]][$keys[1]][$keys[2]];
        break;
    case 4:
        if(array_isset($array[$keys[0]][$keys[1]][$keys[2]][$keys[3]]), $array[$keys[0]][$keys[1]][$keys[2]])
            $value = $array[$keys[0]][$keys[1]][$keys[2]][$keys[3]];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

function array_isset($key, Array $array) {
  if(isset($array[$key])) {
    return true;
  }
  return array_key_exists($key, $array);
}
```

Any better idea? I don't want to use eval

---

Updated, so the final code according to Alma Do Mundo

```
$result = $array[$keys[0]];
for($i=1;$i<count($keys);$i++) {
    if(array_isset($keys[$i], $result))
        $result = $result[$keys[$i]];
    else {
        $result = null;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dare I say it.. `eval` might be useful here with `implode()`, though there are no doubt other solutions, this would probably be quickest (and still safe if implemented correctly)

Comment: Yes, eval would work here – the other alternative is to do it recursively: First get access to $array[$key[1]], then within that access key2, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a simple loop:

```
//for PHP <=5.3 replace short [] to array()
$rgData   = ['key1'=>['key2'=>['key3'=>'test', 'key4'=>'data'], 'key5'=>'done']];
$rgKeys   = ['key1','key2','key3'];
$rgResult = $rgData[$rgKeys[0]];
for($i=1; $i<count($rgKeys); $i++)
{
   $rgResult=$rgResult[$rgKeys[$i]];
}
```

There could be an option with `eval`, but I'd say - never use `eval` - if you can avoid it.

Comment: This is smart, much better than mine!